# Importing global styles in scss without duplicating scss on each component

Tags: angular, sass

I have some scss files which contain some atomik classes :

**atomik.scss**

```
.w-100 { width: 100%}
.w-75 { width: 75%}
.w-60 { width: 60%}
[...] //dozens of others classes
```

I can use them in HTML :

```
<div class="w-100">
```

Or in other `scss` files :

**foo.component.scss**

```
 @import 'atomik'
 .foo {
   @extend .w-100;
   [...]
 }
```

It seemed neat at the beginning until I realized that the **whole** `atomik.scss` file was copied in each component that imported it. It seems to be the expected behavior of scss.

generated **foo.component.js**

```
[...]
  styles: ["
  .w-100 { width: 100%};
  .w-75 { width: 75%}
  .w-60 { width: 60%}
  [...] //dozens of others classes
  .foo {
    width: 100%
  }"]
[...]
```

There seems to be a solution with [placeholders](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

The **atomik.scss** would then become :

```
%w-100 { width: 100%}
%w-75 { width: 75%}
%w-60 { width: 60%}
[...] //dozens of others classes
```

and **foo.component.scss** would become :

```
@import 'atomik'
.foo {
  @extend %w-100;
  [...]
}
```

and the generated **foo.component.js** :

```
[...]
  styles: ["
  .foo {
    width: 100%
  }"]
[...]
```

**Nice !** But... now the atomik classes cannot be used in HTML anymore :

```
<div class="%w-100"> <!-- will be interpreted as class %w-100 -->
```

How can I make those CSS properties reusable in HTML without manually redefining all the properties in a scss that would be globally declared.

Is there a common pattern ?

Comment: If `atomik.scss` is global you could just `@import 'atomik'` on your `style.scss` provided by angular. Or import via `angular.json`

Comment: @penleychan I don't get it. From what I understand, that would not make those properties accessible from HTML. The placeholders would just behave like scss variables.

Answer (score 0):

All classes declared in the global `style.scss` are, by default, available for all your components in your angular application.
You should be adding any such widely used stylesheet in `style.scss` to make it available for entire application.

You can import your  `atomik.scss` in `styles.scss` and it will solve your problem. just be careful about the import orders of the `scss` files in here, if there are multiple imports you may end up overriding few classes. Also make sure `atomik.scss` is written in a way to be applied to other components ( considering parent-child style classes).